# How to compare column data with entire table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have sample result set :

```
declare @Emp Table (Emp_Name VARCHAR(10),Dept_name VARCHAR(10),Subjects VARCHAR(10),Score VARCHAR(10))
Insert into @EMP(Emp_Name,Dept_name,Subjects,Score)VALUES ('MOHAN','LANGUAGES','English',35)
Insert into @EMP(Emp_Name,Dept_name,Subjects,Score)VALUES ('MOHAN','LANGUAGES','TELUGU',35)
Insert into @EMP(Emp_Name,Dept_name,Subjects,Score)VALUES ('MOHAN','SCIENCE','BIOLOGY',35)
Insert into @EMP(Emp_Name,Dept_name,Subjects,Score)VALUES ('MOHAN','SCIENCE','PHYSICS',35)
Insert into @EMP(Emp_Name,Dept_name,Subjects,Score)VALUES ('MOHAN','SOCIAL','ECONOMICS',35)
Insert into @EMP(Emp_Name,Dept_name,Subjects,Score)VALUES ('MOHAN','SOCIAL','CIVICS',35)
Insert into @EMP(Emp_Name,Dept_name,Subjects,Score)VALUES ('MOHAN','SOCIAL','ECONOMICS',35)
```

**Sample Data** :

```
Emp_Name    Dept_name   Subjects    Score
MOHAN     LANGUAGES     English      35
MOHAN     LANGUAGES     TELUGU       35
MOHAN     SCIENCE       BIOLOGY      35
MOHAN     SCIENCE       PHYSICS      35
MOHAN     SOCIAL        ECONOMICS    35
MOHAN     SOCIAL        CIVICS       35
MOHAN     SOCIAL        ECONOMICS    35
```

Need to compare entire table data with each column data :

```
Select COUNT(*) ALL_COl FROM (
select  Emp_Name,Dept_name,Subjects,Score from  @Emp )T


Select Count(*) Without_Subject_Col FROM (
select DISTINCT Emp_Name,Dept_name,Score from  @Emp)TT

Select count(*) Without_Dept_Col from (
select DISTINCT Emp_Name,Subjects,Score from  @Emp )TTT

Select COUNT(*) Without_Dept_Subject_Col from (
select DISTINCT Emp_Name,Score from  @Emp )TTTT
```

How can I get the output like this :

```
ALL_COL  Without_Subject_Col   Without_Dept_Col   Without_Dept_Subject_Col
 7             3                     6                   1
```

Suggest me the way how to achieve it

Comment: Have you tried `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`?

Comment: I'm trying to dynamic pivot ..don't want to give all column names checking each count . Suggest me

Comment: so this is an XY question?   You should either edit your question to ask what you're really asking, or accept Sean's answer, which does answer the question you asked.  Although now that three people have answered the question you asked, instead of editing, you should probably close this question by accepting an answer and ask a new one.

Comment: Couldn't agree more @TabAlleman. This seems to be a changing question also. Now that it was answered we have new requirements which indicates even more clearly that the approach being taken is probably not the best approach. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why you want this but using count with distinct makes this pretty simple.

```
Select ALL_COL = COUNT(*) 
    , Without_Subject_Col = Count(DISTINCT Emp_Name + Dept_name + convert(varchar(5), Score))
    , Without_Dept_Col = count(distinct Emp_Name + Subjects + convert(varchar(5), Score))
    , Without_Dept_Subject_Col = count(distinct Emp_Name + convert(varchar(5), Score))
from  @Emp
```

Comment: thanks for answering for example if  I have lot more columns say around 12 to  15 columns then it will be difficult to add all columns in COUNT(DISTINCT COL1 + COL2 +COL3 ....)..is there any way to do dynamic Pivot or Loop

Comment: Any other new requirements? Nothing worse than answering a question only to find out that only part of it was asked. To be honest I don't understand the logic of what columns you are using in your count.

Comment: I have mentioned in question sample data but in reality it will be larger sets . More over in my question itself I have written the answer with COUNT and DISTINCT. I have asked for suggestion in Dynamic PIVOT or any other way..

Comment: How about posting what you are really trying to accomplish. Whatever this attempt of a partial dynamic pivot just makes no sense. And no, you did not even attempt to indicate that this was  dynamic pivot in your question.

Comment: i'm good with your answer and asking for a suggestion on multiple columns. lets start it from here

Comment: OK that starts with you. Begin by explaining what you want because at this point I have no idea what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188489/discussion-between-mohan111-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 1):

You could just OUTER APPLY the counts?

```
 select top 1 a.ALL_COl, 
              aa.Without_Subject_Col, 
              aaa.Without_Dept_Col, 
              aaaa.Without_Dept_Subject_Col 
 from @EMP e
    outer apply 
        (Select COUNT(*) ALL_COl FROM (
         select  Emp_Name,Dept_name,Subjects,Score from  @Emp )T ) A
    outer apply
        (Select Count(*) Without_Subject_Col FROM (
        select DISTINCT Emp_Name,Dept_name,Score from  @Emp)TT ) AA
    outer apply
        (Select count(*) Without_Dept_Col from (
        select DISTINCT Emp_Name,Subjects,Score from  @Emp )TTT)AAA
    outer apply
        (Select COUNT(*) Without_Dept_Subject_Col from (
        select DISTINCT Emp_Name,Score from  @Emp )TTTT)AAAA
```

Answer (score 1):

Just select the counts as sub-queries

```
SELECT 
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Emp
) AS ALL_Col,
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Emp_Name, Dept_name, Score FROM @Emp) q
) AS Without_Subject_Col,
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Emp_Name, Subjects, Score FROM @Emp) q
) AS Without_Dept_Col,
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Emp_Name, Score FROM @Emp) q
) AS Without_Dept_Subject_Col;
```

A test on *rextester* [here](https://rextester.com/QABSO85247)